# Run python unittest in context of specific directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

In my python application, I open mp3 files with relative paths from where the program was started. To keep it simple, I made a minimal reproduction of the problem I have in my project [here](https://github.com/CoreyCole/unittest-py).

Basically, I have a structure like this:

```
src
└─ main.py
test
└─ test_main.py
```

In `main.py` I have a simple function that prints and returns the current working directory:

```python
def get_cwd() -> str:
    directory = os.path.basename(os.getcwd())
    print('Current directory =', directory)
    return directory
```

So if I `cd` into the `src` folder and run `python main.py` I see:

```
Current directory = src
```

This is the desired behavior, as in my program the file paths to the mp3 files are relative to `src`.

The problem arises when I try to write tests. I can't seem to get a test like this to pass, no matter what I pass to `--start-directory` and `--top-level-directory`:

```python
def test_get_cwd(self):
    print('testing get_cwd()')
    current_dir = get_cwd()
    self.assertIsNotNone(current_dir)
    self.assertEqual(current_dir, 'src')
```

**The question:** How can I run my tests as if they were running in the context of a specific directory if they are saved to a different directory?

Constraints:

- the tests must import using absolute paths, as in my example: `from
  src.main import get_cwd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `os` function to change the directory, try adding `os.chdir('src')` to your test.

```
import unittest
import os

from src.main import get_cwd


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_cwd(self):
        os.chdir('src')
        print('testing get_cwd()')
        current_dir = get_cwd()
        self.assertIsNotNone(current_dir)
        self.assertEqual(current_dir, 'src')
```

Comment: Yes! This works and fits my real program's constraints. Thank you @javrd!

Answer (score 2):

An option is to [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) the value given by `os.path.basename` with a return value of `"src"`

```
import unittest
from mock import patch

from src.main import get_cwd


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('os.path.basename')
    def test_get_cwd(self, basename):
        basename.return_value = "src"
        print('testing get_cwd()')
        current_dir = get_cwd()
        self.assertIsNotNone(current_dir)
        self.assertEqual(current_dir, 'src')
```

Comment: That would work for this simple example, but in my real project, I need the **real** cwd to be `src` so that the program can find the mp3 files with the same file paths as when it runs normally. The example I made was just to minimally reproduce my problem, I'm not actually using `os.getcwd()` in my real program, I just need it to return the expected directory so I know it can find the mp3 files with the same relative file paths.

Comment: I think it should work. Maybe you have to mock something more, but if the path to yours mp3 is fixed depending on your workspace, I don't see why not mocking these path in your controlled test case.

Comment: It won't work for my real program. I have code that loads up mp3s using relative file paths like `audio/example.mp3` where the full path is `src/audio/example.mp3`. Mocking what cwd or basename returns will not help this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I often do this to create a temporary directory for each test, particularly when testing a file parsing script.

```py
import unittest
import tempfile
import os

class TempDirTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create temp folder (deleted when test is done)
        self.tempdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
        self.addCleanup(self.tempdir.cleanup)

        # Remember original CWD, and go back there after each test
        self._origin_cwd = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.tempdir.name)
        def _revert_cwd():
            os.chdir(self._origin_cwd)
        self.addCleanup(_revert_cwd)

    def test_stuff(self):
        # Create all the relative files & folders you want
        os.mkdir('./nested')
        with open('nested/foo.txt', 'w') as fh:
            fh.write('bar')
```

This will create a new folder per test (with cleanup), so the files created in one won't influence the next.

Note: If doing lots of tests, or very frequently (eg: Continuous Integration), consider pointing `tempfile` to a ramdisk, this will increase speed, and lifetime of the disk.

Also consider making your code interface with `StreamIO` objects instead of filename `str`s, but this doesn't suit all situations.